# Conditionally block Jenkins jobs based on parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have 2 Jenkins jobs - Jenkins_Job1 and Jenkins_Job2, both have string parameter.
Jenkins_Job1 after running successfully kicks off Jenkins_Job2 for the same parameter(3 letters abc/def/ghi etc is the parametr value).
Build names of jobs are built based on the parameter value followed by sequence number.

```
Queue for Jenkins_Job1:
abc_Build4
ghi_Build5


Queue for Jenkins_Job2:
**abc_Build1
def_Build2**
ghi_Build3
abc_Build4
ghi_Build5
```

Suppose abc_Build1, def_Build2 are currently running in Jenkins_Job2, the next job in the queue for Jenkins_Job1 abc_Build4 shouldn't run. It should be blocked and run only after abc_Build1 in Jenkins_Job2 completes.

Is there any plugin that can be used for this?
To be able to block the job based on the parameter.
Any help is appreciated.